# RSA algorithm works for Android 4.3 but crash for Android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, algorithm, encryption, rsa

I am trying to encrypt a file using the RSA algorithm with a public key (which I build using a given modulus and exponent).

My code works fine with Android 4.3, and I get all I need. But I am trying to make it work for other Android versions such (2.3.3) and there is no way. It complains about a "input too large for RSA cipher". 
If I have understood the theory well the block cipher size is relative to the publicKey.size(), therefore if this don't change from one version of Android to another I should get the same result, should't I?

Here is my code:
package com.example.rsa_ex;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private byte[] mKeyModulus = {...};
    private byte[] mKeyExponent = {...};

    private String tag = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String token = "";
        try
        {
            token = readTokenFromFile("token.base64");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(tag, "Failed to open property file");
        }

        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encode(token.getBytes(), 0);

        Log.d(tag, "Encrypt Token"+ onEncrypt(encodedBytes));
    }

    public String readTokenFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException  
    {  
        String token = "empty";

        try
        {  
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream iS = assetManager.open(fileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[iS.available()];    
            iS.read(buffer);  

            ByteArrayOutputStream oS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  

            oS.write(buffer);  
            token = oS.toString();
            oS.close();  
            iS.close(); 

            Log.d(tag, "token ==> "+token);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(tag, "Failed to open property file");
        }

        return token; 

    } // readTokenFromFile end 
    public String onEncrypt(byte[] token)
    {   
        Log.d(tag,"onEncrypt entry");
        String encryptedTranspherable = "";//null;
        // get the publicKey
        try
        {
            BigInteger m = new BigInteger(mKeyModulus);
            BigInteger e = new BigInteger(mKeyExponent);

            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            Key pubKey = fact.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e));

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

            byte[] encrypted = blockCipher(token,cipher);
            encryptedTranspherable = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("serialisation error got issue here !! ==>"+ e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return encryptedTranspherable;
    }// onEncrypt end

    private byte[] blockCipher(byte[] bytes,Cipher cipher) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        Log.d(tag,"ISecurityProvider blockCipher entry");
        Log.d(tag,"ISecurityProvider byteArray =>"+ Arrays.toString(bytes));
        byte[] scrambled = new byte[0];

        // toReturn will hold the total result
        byte[] toReturn = new byte[0];
        int length = 256; 

        // another buffer. this one will hold the bytes that have to be modified in this step
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.min(bytes.length, length)];//(bytes.length > length ? length : bytes.length)];
        for (int i=0; i< bytes.length; i++)
        {
            // if we filled our buffer array we have our block ready for de- or encryption
            if ((i > 0) && (i % length == 0))
            {
                Log.d(tag,"ISecurityProvider blockCipher processing block  i ="+i);
                scrambled = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
                toReturn = append(toReturn,scrambled);

                // here we calculate the length of the next buffer required
                int newlength = length;

                // if newlength would be longer than  remaining bytes in the bytes array we shorten it.
                if (i + length > bytes.length) 
                {
                    newlength = bytes.length - i;
                }
                // clean the buffer array
                buffer = new byte[newlength];
            }
            // copy byte into our buffer.
            buffer[i%length] = bytes[i];
        }

        // this step is needed if we had a trailing buffer. should only happen when encrypting.
        // example: we encrypt 110 bytes. 100 bytes per run means we "forgot" the last 10 bytes. they are in the buffer array
        scrambled = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
        // final step before we can return the modified data.
        toReturn = append(toReturn,scrambled);

        return toReturn;
    }

    private byte[] append(byte[] prefix, byte[] suffix)
    {
        byte[] toReturn = new byte[prefix.length + suffix.length];

        int prefixSize = prefix.length;
        int  suffixSize = suffix.length;

        for (int i=0; i< prefixSize; i++)
        {
            toReturn[i] = prefix[i];
        }

        for (int i=0; i< suffixSize; i++)
        {
            toReturn[i+prefixSize] = suffix[i];
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion or advise will be more than welcome.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not directly on-topic but I recommend post small parts of your code that you presume might be giving out the error

Comment: Well in the Android 2.3.3, it complains exactly the 1st time that try to do the cipher.doFinal(buffer), because "apparently" the buffer is to0 big for that cipher (input data too large for RSA cipher).  But that makes no sense for me as in Android 4.3 it works perfectly. I was wondering if there could be something else.

Comment: Is it possible that they use a different version of the security provider BC?

Comment: I suggest you read http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html and try the implementation there, which should be correct for all API levels.

Comment: @IVlad The idiot that wrote that should be shot and keelhauled, then shot again to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android 4.2 enhancements:

> Cryptography - Modified the default implementations of SecureRandom and Cipher.RSA to use OpenSSL. Added SSL Socket support for TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 using OpenSSL 1.0.1

This means that they are using another provider, and probably another *default* RSA padding mechanism. You should always provide a complete algorithm string and not rely on provider defaults, e.g. try `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"` for new applications and `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` for compatibility with older libraries.

Note that you usually do not encrypt a file directly using RSA. Usually you encrypt the file with a random data key using e.g. AES, a symmetric cipher. Then you encrypt that AES key with the RSA public key and send the result with the ciphertext. This way you can encrypt an (almost) arbitrary number of bytes. This is called [hybrid cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this don't work in my case. Adding a bit more of information I have realised that Android 2.3.3 is using a BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.45 while Android 4.3 BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.48. When I ask them to implement the RSA algorithm. Is there any way to add the version of the BC that I want with a .jar in my project an use that one instead of the one that it's in the device.

Comment: Only for newer versions of Android. If I understood correctly, they have now moved Bouncy out of its default namespace (packages) so you should be able to use it next to the (circumsized) Android version. Otherwise use Spongy Castle as first provider (a Bouncy Castle provider with implementation in a different namespace). Note that this does not invalidate what I said above, if Bouncy/Spongy uses a different default... And PKCS1Padding should always work with the default provider too.

Comment: I've tried to import the SpongyCastle as well, but it doesn't work either.  If I set up my cipher using (RSA/ECB/NoPadding) it works in Android 4.3 as it calls the AndroidOpenSSL but if fails in the Android 2.3.3 as it keeps calling the BC. Is there any way to use the new security providers with the old versions of android. I am very stack here, I don't really know what else I can try.

Comment: Padding is an integral part of RSA security. If you leave it out you leave yourself exposed. Use the hybrid approach with (at least) PKCS1Padding and your problems will disappear.